# tmux color theme in emacs gtk

Tags: emacs, tmux, colors

When I use emacs -nw I always use it in tmux 256-color mode. tmux applies its default color theme to emacs so it looks like this:

[image: emacs running in tmux]

For some reason I like that color theme far better than any other emacs theme I've tried.

My question is: how can I get the same color theme when I run emacs in the normal X mode?

I've searched around but I haven't found out if the default tmux color theme (that it applies to bash and other programs as well) even have a name ...